# Display Custom Post Object match

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called 'review' and this has a post object field called 'employee'.

On my staff page (/staff/mike) I would like to display all reviews where my custom field Employee = "mike".

I can get and display all the reviews by all staff, but I want to only query them where the Employee field matches "Mike" exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a meta field at review post type for employee names. And at staff page you can make a WP_Query of reviews with the meta value of current staff name. For details about meta query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end.

On a single 'employee' page (site.com/employee/mike) I do a WP_Query for all reviews. My custom post type 'review' has a post_object select field called 'employee'.

If the current page title i.e "Mike" matches the field in the employee object for review, then I display the results.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'review', 
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);   

$title = get_the_title(); // Get current page title = "Mike"

while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $employee = get_field('employee');

    if ($employee->post_title == $title) : 
        the_title();  // Display all reviews by Mike
    endif; 

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```